# how can i use roborealm software (vision for machines) in ros?

Tags: ros, nxt, lego

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear sirs,
Hello. I want to know how can i use roborealm software for my Lego nxt in Ros ?? I have created my robot model in Lego digital designer and i want to convert it into robot models compatible with ROS and then i want to use roborealm for vision part of my Lego robot.
how can I use roborealm software in Ros ??
thanks
Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10379/how-can-i-use-roborealm-software-(vision-for-machines)-in-ros-??/) by [khabar](https://answers.ros.org/users/732/khabar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've used Roborealm a little about a year ago.  I wasn't terribly impressed with it, but it was fairly easy to get something simple going.  I think it's Windows only, so you're going to need at least two computers for now (one Windows for Roborealm, one Linux for ROS).

I didn't have much luck with them, but Roborealm has a [list of interfaces](http://www.roborealm.com/help/Integration.php) that it supports.  Of these, you should take the closest look at the [text sockets API](http://www.roborealm.com/help/Socket_Comm.php).  As long as you can define your output as ASCII, decimal, hex, or binary then you can pipe that over the network and use it as you want in C++, etc.

---

That's an awful lot of work, so I'd suggest learning [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).  You can then be all on one machine without a great number of hacks (so no virtualization).  OpenCV has most of the image processing techniques that Roborealm does, or you can at least find a compatible library.  A good book to learn OpenCV is [Learning OpenCV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) by the guys who started OpenCV.

If you're using Roborealm for everything (keyboard/joystick driving, AI, etc), then it will be a lot more work to convert to ROS, but I think it's really worth it.  RoboRealm is pretty limited and you're also stuck with the languages they have plugins for.  Learning ROS will also give you lots of employable skills and a better understanding of how things work.  We may also have better support with ROS answers!

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-27**:
@khabar, have you checked out the nxt stack in ROS?  http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt

**Comment by [khabar](https://answers.ros.org/users/732/khabar/) on 2011-06-23**:
Dear sir thanks for your response. the reason  that i use roborealm is that it has Lego NXT module and i can read all my Lego sensors from this program and command to motors. i have already wrote a program in roborealm with Vb-script and control my Lego successfully . so i need roborealm in Ros